# identity authentication using custom database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I am creating asp.net identity authentication. I am following this article http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/

I have a User class that extends from IUser
and following classes

```
 CustomSignInManager:SignInManager<User,string>
 CustomUserManager : UserManager<User>
 CustomUserStore : IUserStore<CustomUser>
```

And I have LINQ to SQL class

Following is my CustomUserStore class

```
 public class CustomUserStore:IUserStore<User>
{
    private UserDataDataContext database;
    public CustomUserStore()
    {
        this.database = new UserDataDataContext();

    }

    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        // TODO
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.database.Dispose();
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(User user)
    {
        // TODO
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(User user)
    {
        // TODO
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        User user = await this.database.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return user;
    }
    public async Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        User user = await this.database.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return user;
    }
}
```

The problem I am getting is with following line

```
     User user = await this.database.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

in

```
 public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
```

method

The error I am getting is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'testSys.User' to 'testSys.Models.User'  testSys testSys\testSys\Models\CustomUserStore.cs   49  Active

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you have 2 `User` class types in your project?

Comment: @DavidG I have a model class User that extends from IUser<string> and one user class is created by linq to sql and it's like this "public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged"